# React: Рендер функционального компонента только в случае изминения Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, state

Рендер функционального компонента только в случае изминения props?

В приложении одновременно отображается несколько компонентов:

```
<comp1 {...props}>
<comp2 {...props}>
<comp3 {...props}>
```

Компонент `comp3` использует кнопку фильтр для отображения вибраних категорий объектов из пропса `props.objects.categories`.

При изминении пропсов в `comp1` или `comp2` все три компонента перерендериваются тем самим обнуляя фильтр, как заблокировать рендер `comp3` в случае если его пропси не менялись?

Comment: Ты как-то неправильно готовишь реакт. Код в студию

Answer (score 1):

Если у всех трех компонентов различное поведение и им требуются только некоторые props, то и незачем передавать всем весь многоуровневый объект. Тогда они и будут рендериться только при изменении конкретных значений.

```
<comp1 foo={props.foo}/>
<comp2 bar={props.bar}/>
<comp3 categories={props.objects.categories}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если **comp3** это классовый компонент тогда можешь ограничить рендер используя метод `shouldComponetnUpdate`.

Пример:

```
shouldComponetnUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.category !== this.props.category;
}
```

То же самое можно провернуть с функциональным компонентом используя `React.useMemo()`

Comment: Я пробивал и то и то,  в данном случае оно  не работает.